# PhpStorm and two-factor authentication

Tags: php, ssh, phpstorm, two-factor-authentication

I am developing for a website that uses two factor authentication (via password and SMS code). Using SSH and ControlMaster and ControlPersist in the .ssh/config file, I can successfully log in (after the first verification) without having to enter the SMS code again. This works just fine for the shell, but I also need to use PhpStorm to edit/upload files. I searched, but could not find any reference on how to use two-factor authentication with PhpStorm.

Can I tell PhpStorm to use the .ssh/config options and use the control connection? Is there a way to use two-factor authentication in PhpStorm? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I solved this by use sshfs to mount the filesystem locally (which requires two-factor auth), and then PhpStorm just writes to the local directory.